# upload file with angular and backend laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, upload

i want to upload photo with angular and backend laravel, but the photos I uploaded does not enter into the upload folder laravel

why?
angular js
http://pastebin.com/URbznpFQ
Controller Upload
http://pastebin.com/q7Yje7se

What Should I Do? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
$path = public_path() . '/../upload/form';
```

into

```
$path = public_path() . '/upload/form/';
```

Make sure your folder path does exists and give the appropriate permissions to upload folder as below.

```
chmod -R 777 [directory where you are storing the images]
```

Hope this helps.